# How to wrap(in span) words in a text editor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript variable like this:

```
var text = "A <mark id='1'>businessman</mark> should be able to <mark id='1'>manage</mark> his business matters";
```

I want to wrap each word in a span element with a different id but leave the words which are already wrapped in the `<mark>` tags. Like this:

```
text = "<span id='1'>A </span><mark id='1'>businessman</mark><span id='2'>should</span><span id='3'>be </span><span id='4'>able </span><span id='5'>to </span><mark id='2'>manage</mark><span id='6'>his </span><span id='7'>business </span><span id='8'>matters</span>";
```

I want all this in javascript or jquery but couldn't get it. It would be nice if you people can help me.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish. Do you have a variable which contains a string (e.g. a sentence) and you want to transform that variable into another string where each word is wrapped in an html element?

Comment: So individual words that are not already inside a `<mark>` tag should be wrapped in a `<span>` tag with unique IDs? Does it matter that in your sample output the first span has the same ID that all of the mark elements do?

Comment: @nnnnnn I didn't saw the jQuery in q body. my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The following quick and dirty method removes the spaces from the `<mark id='1'>` elements so that the whole string can then be split on spaces, allowing individual words to be wrapped as needed, then it's joined back together, and finally the `<mark>` elements are restored and renumbered:

```js
var text = "A <mark id='1'>businessman</mark> should be able to <mark id='1'>manage</mark> his business matters";
var spanIndex = 1;
var markIndex = 1;
var result = text.replace(/<mark id='1'>/g,'<mark>')
  .split(' ')
  .map(function(v){
    return v.slice(0,6)==='<mark>' ? v : "<span id='" + spanIndex++ + "'>" + v + '</span>'
  })
  .join(' ')
  .replace(/<mark>/g, function() { return "<mark id='" + markIndex++ + "'>"});
console.log(result);
```

Note: you said you want to "leave the words which are already wrapped in the `<mark>` tags", but then your sample output had renumbered the mark element ids (input had both as `id='1'`, but output had `1` and `2`). So I've shown code that renumbers, but obviously if you didn't mean to do that you can just make the final `.replace()` a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```js
function removeEmptyStrings(k) {
  return k !== '';
}

function getWordsArray(div) {
  var rWordBoundary = /[\s\n\t]+/; // split by tab, newline, spaces
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < div.childNodes.length; ++i) { // Iterate through all nodes
    var node = div.childNodes[i];
    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) { // The child is a text node
      var words = node.nodeValue.split(rWordBoundary).filter(removeEmptyStrings); // check for emptyness
      for (var j = 0, l = words.length; j < l; j++) {
        // adding class txtSpan so that it will not affect your spans already available in your input.
        output.push('<span class="txtSpan">' + words[j] + '</span>');
      }
    } else { // add directly if not a text node
      output.push(node.outerHTML);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
var counter = 1,
  html = getWordsArray($('#editor')[0]).join('');
$('#output').html(html).find('span.txtSpan').each(function() {
  this.id = 'span-' + counter++;
});
```

```css
span.txtSpan {
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
  A <mark id='1'>businessman</mark> should be able to <mark id='1'>manage</mark> his business matters
</div>
<div id="output">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a much simpler approach that uses **the browser's native DOM** to parse and transform.

The idea here is to:

1. create an empty element and don't add it to the document.
2. take your text you want to transform and wrap and set it as the `innerHTML` of the temp element.
3. create an array from the `childNodes` of the temp element (created when you set the `innerHTML`)
4. if the childNode has a `nodeValue` then it was a text node NOT wrapped in a `mark` tag. In this case, create a new span element
5. in the case where the node is already wrapped in an element, just return the element
6. while you do all of this, remap the IDs to the index they were in from the array. this way they are unique.

Since you're settingthe innerHTML of an element, the DOM will actually fix any mistakes and you get perfect HTML out :)

```js
var text = "A <mark id='1'>businessman</mark> should be able to <mark id='1'>manage</mark> his business matters";

const tempElement = document.createElement('div');
tempElement.innerHTML = text;

let final = Array.from(tempElement.childNodes).map((node, index) => {
  if (node.nodeValue) { // if the node is a text node
    let newSpanElement = document.createElement('span');
    newSpanElement.id = index; // assign an ID
    newSpanElement.innerText = node.nodeValue;
    return newSpanElement;
  }
  // else it's inside another element
  node.id = index; // reassign the id
  return node;
}).map(node => node.outerHTML).join('');
console.log(final);
```